# Is there any way to avoid/workaround that users are logging automatically by consuming their windows context instead of via username & password?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Some team implemented some changes recently. Since that time users are logging to web app automatically by consuming their windows context instead of via username & password.

This has the side effect that you can't really authenticate with a different user. As a result we're lost all our UI automation test(Java + Selenium) as we cannot perform all necessary actions using just one authorized user.

Is there any way to workaround this?

Comment: @Dmitrity : are you using chrome profile?

Comment: Could you provide the browser launching code ?

Comment: What do you mean by `windows-context`. Are you using SSO to log in?

Comment: Yes, SSO login.

Comment: What about let selenium to log in as current windows user, log him off and initiate new login to the web app? Is in such scenario user logged automatically as well or 'old' credentials input is required?

Comment: Or if the web app has saved credetials in Windows, you can allways get rid of it. Without saved credentials new input must be required.

Comment: I was thinking about it...but browser gets closed after I clicked logoff. And then you need to start browser once again and again autologin will be applied.

Comment: I think I need to intercept http request before it will be sent to server and maybe replace it with some clean request and the server will ask for credentials... but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: First of all ask the 'some team' if even 'old' login method still possible. If yes, you need to know where the credentials are saved. In SSO architecture you have to obtain an access token. It depends on implementation how access token are provided.

Comment: Today I find out that 'old' login still possible on FF) So, after some investigation I found that Symantec Chrome extension was installed exactly before 'old' login stopped working and I have no rights to disable it ((( Will try to run CH disable extension option...